# Compute the limit as $t \to 0$ of the given expression

Tags: limits

Consider the expression $$\frac{t^6(t^2x^2+t^2y^2-2z^2)}{(t^4x^2+t^4y^2+t^2z^2)^{5/2}}.$$

I want to compute the limit as $t \to 0$.

My guess is that the expression will tend to zero as $t$ tends to zero because the numerator has higher powers of $t$ and therefore it will tend to zero faster than the denominator. I'm not sure how to show this formally though.

Comment: it is basically $-2z^2t^6/Ct^{10}$ so your limit will be infinite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t^6(t^2x^2+t^2y^2-2z^2)}{(t^4x^2+t^4y^2+t^2z^2)^{5/2}}=lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t^6(t^2x^2+t^2y^2-2z^2)}{t^{5}(t^2x^2+t^2y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}=lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{t(t^2x^2+t^2y^2-2z^2)}{(t^2x^2+t^2y^2+z^2)^{5/2}}=0$$